# Running rclone sync on shutdown

Tags: boot, shutdown, systemd, services, rclone

I wanted my cloud storage sync to be performed during system shutdown. For this purpose I use rclone with MEGA cloud storage. So, thanks for guide-writers I got the next:

run_on_shutdown.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Syncing with MEGA cloud storage
DefaultDependencies=no
Before=shutdown.target halt.target
RequiresMountsFor=/home/yevhenii
After=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
User=yevhenii
ExecStart=/home/yevhenii/Projects/ubuntu-scripts/mega_sync_pc.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=halt.target shutdown.target
```

And simple script that it runs:

```
REBOOT=$( systemctl list-jobs | egrep -q 'reboot.target.*start' && echo "rebooting" || echo "not_rebooting" )

if [ $REBOOT = "not_rebooting" ]; then

    echo "Syncronizing Projects" >> /home/yevhenii/log.txt
    #rclone check /home/yevhenii/Projects mega:Projects >> /home/yevhenii/log.txt
    rclone sync /home/yevhenii/Projects mega:Projects >> /home/yevhenii/log.txt
    echo "" >> /home/yevhenii/log.txt

    REPORT=$(systemctl status run_on_shutdown)
    echo $REPORT >> /home/yevhenii/log.txt

fi
```

Result: it doesn't work. this script runs on shutdown, but i don't receive any messages from rclone. It only prints "Syncronizing Projects" in log file. Neither sync, not check - is working. What's wrong with this ? Executing 'rclone check' in command line results in very quick respond (1-2 sec), meanwhile shut downing stretched out up to 10 seconds or even more.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to put an appropriate `ExecStop=` line and appropriate `After=` lines in the `[Service]` section.

---

Anyway, I have a similar script. It does not do `rsync`; but it does other network related things during system START and also during system STOP.

I am using the following service definition (file: `/lib/systemd/system/zzz-my-sss.service`)

```
[Unit]
Description=Execute system START and STOP script
After=network.target syslog.target
After=systemd-user-sessions.service
After=network-online.target

[Service]
User=_my_user_
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/home/_my_user_/path/to/my/script.sh START
RemainAfterExit=true
ExecStop=/home/_my_user_/path/to/my/script.sh STOP
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Here `_my_user_` is my normal Ubuntu user. The script `/home/_my_user_/path/to/my/script.sh` will be called during system startup (after network is up) with a parameter `START`. Similarly, it will be called during system shutdown (before network goes down) with a parameter `STOP`.

You should enable this service using:

```
# systemctl enable zzz-my-sss.service
```

You can start / stop it manually using:

```
# systemctl start zzz-my-sss.service
# systemctl status zzz-my-sss.service
# systemctl list-units | grep zzz-my-sss.service
# systemctl stop zzz-my-sss.service
```

And disable it using:

```
# systemctl disable zzz-my-sss.service
```

If you update it, do not forget to run:

```
# systemctl daemon-reload
```

Comment: "WantedBy=multi-user.target" going this way I can't distinguish reboot from shutdown. anyway it doesn't work with rclone. Script runs but rclone doesn't work. It could be interrupted by timeout or by non-working netwotrking. How can I check it ? Running "systemctl start my-service" everything works OK.

Comment: trial and error method forced rclone to return this: Failed to create file system for "mega:Projects": couldn't login: Post https://g.api.mega.co.nz/cs?id=88936976: dial tcp: lookup g.api.mega.co.nz on 127.0.0.53:53: read udp 127.0.0.1:56452->127.0.0.53:53: read: connection refused.

Answer (score 0):

After a bunch of attempts I finally got the solution. I couldn't find the way how to make auto-sync.sh run only on shutdown. So, I just found the way to check it with bash.

Service File

```
[Unit]
Description=Syncing with MEGA cloud storage v100
After=network-online.target

[Service]
User=yevhenii
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/true
ExecStop=/path_to_your_script/auto-sync.sh
RemainAfterExit=true
TimeoutStopSec=0
StandardOutput=tty
StandardError=inherit

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Script file

```
REBOT_FACTOR=$( systemctl list-jobs | egrep -q 'reboot.target.*start' && echo "rebooting" || echo "not_rebooting" )

if [[ "$REBOT_FACTOR" == "not_rebooting" ]]; then
    # You can perform your rclone sync right here.
    # Code here will be started only at shutdown.
fi
```